# Can Eclipse give me warning when casting Boolean to boolean

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, warnings, implicit-conversion

I have been bitten by this error too many times. I have a POJO class such as

```
public class MeasTemplateDefData {
    private Boolean customTemplate;
    public boolean isCustomTemplate() {
        return customTemplate;
    }
}
```

and if customTemplate is null, I get NullPointerException thrown inside the getter.  Often this will happen deep inside some Jackson JSON mapping code, which is very hard to debug.

**Is there any way to tell Eclipse to warn me every time I try to implicitly convert *Boolean* to *boolean*?**

By the way, to make this safe, I would rewrite it, such as

```
    public boolean isCustomTemplate() {
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(customTemplate);
    }
```

assuming null means false.

Comment: You could set your compliance level to 1.4, so autoboxing won't even be available :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can highlight auto(un)boxed expressions in the editor: go to Preferences->Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring and change this option to something striking. This way you won't overlook boxing without too many warnings.

[image: this option]

And look at the Java Compiler->Errors/Warnings under section 'Potential programming problems' - there's a warning for Boxing and unboxing conversions.

Comment: works like a charm!  I wish it would highlight **unboxing** only, but that's better than nothing.